# ZF1 Капча при использовании русских символов выдает последний символ как английскую букву

Tags: php, zend-framework, captcha, recaptcha

ZF1 Капча при использовании русских символов выдает последний символ как английскую букву

Всем привет. Кто сможет подсказать в каком направлении думать?
Я знаю где возникает ошибка, а именно в ядре зенда в `abstract class Zend_Captcha_Word` в этом методе

```
/**
 * Generate new random word
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function _generateWord()
{
    $word       = '';
    $wordLen    = $this->getWordLen();
    $vowels     = $this->_useNumbers ? self::$VN : self::$V;
    $consonants = $this->_useNumbers ? self::$CN : self::$C;

    $totIndexCon = count($consonants) - 1;
    $totIndexVow = count($vowels) - 1;
    for ($i=0; $i < $wordLen; $i = $i + 2) {
        // generate word with mix of vowels and consonants
        $consonant = $consonants[Zend_Crypt_Math::randInteger(0, $totIndexCon, true)];
        $vowel     = $vowels[Zend_Crypt_Math::randInteger(0, $totIndexVow, true)];
        $word     .= $consonant . $vowel;
    }

    if (strlen($word) > $wordLen) {
        // *******************************************
        // * ВОТ ЗДЕСЬ НУЖНО, ЧТОБЫ БЫЛО mb_substr() *
        // *******************************************
        $word = substr($word, 0, $wordLen);
    }

    return $word;
}
```

Вот пример моего кода как я ее использую

```
Zend_Captcha_Word::$CN = ['а', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ж', 'и', 'к', 'л', 'м', 'н', 'п', 'р', 'с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'э', 'ю', 'я', 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
Zend_Captcha_Word::$VN = range(0, 9);
Zend_Captcha_Word::$V = ['с', 'т', 'у', 'ф', 'х', 'ц', 'ч', 'ш', 'э', 'ю', 'я'];
Zend_Captcha_Word::$C = ['а', 'в', 'г', 'д', 'е', 'ж'];
$element = new Zend_Form_Element_Captcha('captcha', [
    'captcha' => [
        'captcha'        => 'Image',
        'wordLen'        => 7,
        'timeout'        => 120,
        'expiration'     => 300,
        'font'           => './fonts/myfont.ttf',
        'imgDir'         => './captcha/',
        'imgUrl'         => '/captcha/',
        'dotNoiseLevel'  => 40,
        'lineNoiseLevel' => 4,
        'class'          => 'img-thumbnail',
    ]
]);
$element->setRequired(true)
    ->setLabel('Проверочный код')
    ->setAttrib('placeholder', 'Введите число')
   ->setAttrib('class', 'form-control')
    ->addDecorator(['row' => 'HtmlTag'], ['tag' => 'div', 'class' => 'form-group']);
$this->addElement($element);
```

Иногда она отображает символ как нужно, а иногда нет

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Функцию замените в методе, да и все. И о баге можно видимо сюда https://github.com/zendframework/zf1/issues отписаться.

Comment: Я так думал уже, но мне кажется это слишком хардкорно.